# How to use fetch() in react native with headers json?

Tags: react-native, fetch

Postman output:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type:  application/json
Date:          Fri, 08 Feb 2019 12:13:36 GMT

{"status":1,"msg":"success","celeb":[{"id":1,"name":"Test Name"....
```

I'm getting my json in postman like this.
when I try to use `fetch()`, I'm getting an error `json parse error, unknown identifier HTTP`

```
fetch('https://myurl/fetch')
.then((response) => response.json())
   .then((response) => {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let func = async () => {
 const url = 'https://myurl/fetch';
 const data = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          token: await AsyncStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN), /*or whatever you have on your api*/
        }),
      };

  const response = await fetch(url , data);
  const responseData = await response.json();

  console.log(responseData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing to set to configure you API call method, headers, mode etc... Check out [Fetch Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for a better explanation.